# date input field is taking more than 4 character in vue js input type date

Tags: vue.js, date, input

I am using Vuejs 3 and when I use input type date it is taking up to 6 characters in the year field. Is there any way to make it take only 4 characters YYYY in the year field?

Comment: Please share your code to what you have achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#additional_attributes) attribute for that. e.g.

```
<input type="date" max="9999-12-31">
```

Comment: But it is not working in Firefox. It is taking up to 6 characters in the year field even if I add max attribute.

Comment: Yes. It's a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1613280). I would recommend using third party date picker instead.